# javax.servlet.ServletException: <p:ajax> Event:rowEdit is not supported

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I am getting an error message while trying to use PrimeFaces for my making each row editable. I was checking online many people are making use of this. However when I am trying to create a page with a report in which each row can be edited. I get error that Event:rowEdit is not supported. Can someone please point out my mistake or something I need to include in my XHTML file. Or If i'm doing things right at all.
This table has lot of data that's why I took this approach

Below is the additional information regarding my setup :

1. Glassfish v3
2. JPA2.1
3. PrimeFaces3.5 (i hve the jar included in my project's build path since other report pages are working to confirm primefaces is working)
4. EJB 3.1

**Here is my XHTML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="userId" value="#{loginBean.username}"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <link href="./css/PageLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Edit Lord of Data Entries</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <div style="background-color: #205a8c; width: auto; height: 60px">
        <h3>Edit Lord Of Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="breadcrumb" align="left">
        <h:form>
            <p:breadCrumb>
                <p:menuitem value="Home" url="home.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Home" url="home.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Users" url="reportUsers.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Groups" url="reportGroups.jsf"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="User's Group" url="reportUserGroup.jsf"></p:menuitem>
            </p:breadCrumb>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"></p:growl>
        <p:dataTable var="myReport"  
            value="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.lodAdmin_list}" id="lodlist"
            editable="true" paginator="true"
            rows="500"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="500,1000,5000">

            <f:facet name="header"> Lord Of Data Report</f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onEditListener}"></p:ajax>
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onCancel}"></p:ajax>

            <p:column>
                <p:rowEditor></p:rowEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Row Id">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Group Id">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.security}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.security}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="Type">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.type}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.type}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Auto">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.auto}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.auto}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Access">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.access}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.access}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Comment">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.comment}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.comment}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD1 Domain">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD1Domain}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD1Domain}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD1 User">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD1User}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD1User}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD1 Mail">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD1Mail}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD1Mail}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD1 Display Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD1DisplayName}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD1DisplayName}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD1 Cost Center">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD1CostCenter}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD1CostCenter}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD2 User">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD2User}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD2User}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="LOD2 Mail">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD2Mail}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD2Mail}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD2 Display Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD2DisplayName}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD2DisplayName}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD2 Cost Center">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD2CostCenter}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD2CostCenter}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Domain1">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.domain1}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.domain1}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="RechteGruppe Read">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.rechteGruppeRead}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.rechteGruppeRead}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="AuthentifizierteBenutzer">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.authentifizierteBenutzer}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.authentifizierteBenutzer}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="LOD2 Domain">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.LOD2Domain}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.LOD2Domain}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Email Send Status">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.emailSendStatus}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.emailSendStatus}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Email Feedback">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.emailFeedback}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.emailFeedback}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Comment1">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.comment1}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.comment1}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Comment2">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.comment2}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.comment2}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Comment 3">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.comment3}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.comment3}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Username">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.username}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.username}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**Managed Bean Code snippet for handling Edit function**

```
public void onEditListener(RowEditEvent event) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edited");

        try {
            Lodreport mydata = (Lodreport) event.getObject();
            if (mydata == null) {
                System.out.println("No data input found");
            } else {
                lODBR.updateReport(mydata);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

     public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Cancelled");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
     }
```

**Error Stack Trace**

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /editNewLODAdmin.xhtml @44,7 <p:ajax> Event:rowEdit is not supported.
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:149)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorHandler.apply(AjaxBehaviorHandler.java:127)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because

1. You technically haven't added row editing support to your table, you're editing a cell. Add a `<p:rowEditor/>` to your table to hook into the `rowEdit` event
2. Your table, it's not a real table. The `<p:dataTable/>` tag doesn't actually wrap the `<p:column/>` or anything else

What you should have:

```
    <p:dataTable var="myReport" value="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.lodAdmin_list}" id="lodlist" editable="true">

            <f:facet name="header"> Lord Of Data Report</f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onEditListener}"
                ></p:ajax>
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onCancel}"
                ></p:ajax>

            <p:column headerText="Row Id">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but somehow the edit button is not editing the rows I am trying to edit. i get to error message to know what is not functioning right. Do you think the controller which is there in my question is the right on? Sorry i am quite new to PrimeFaces so not sure what is happening

Comment: @sushantpandey what error message do you get? Does the row become editable when you click on the edit icon?

Comment: yes it does become editable. However, when I click on the save button after editing row data goes back to the old data and edited data gets lost. There is no error message i checked the console for it.

Comment: I was wondering if my event listener is correctly written or if I am missing something from that method.

Comment: You're not updating (with an `update` attribute on `<p:ajax.>`) the table after the ajax event completes @sushantpandey

Answer (score -1):

I see:

```
<p:dataTable var="myReport"
                    value="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.lodAdmin_list}" id="lodlist"
                    editable="true"></p:dataTable>

                <f:facet name="header"> Lord Of Data Report</f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                    listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onEditListener}"
                    ></p:ajax>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                    listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onCancel}"
                    ></p:ajax>

                <p:column headerText="Row Id">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></h:outputText>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
```

you have to try:

```
    <p:dataTable var="myReport"
                        value="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.lodAdmin_list}" id="lodlist"
                        editable="true">

                    <f:facet name="header"> Lord Of Data Report</f:facet>

                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                        listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onEditListener}"
                        ></p:ajax>
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                        listener="#{lordOfDataAdminManagedBean.onCancel}"
                        ></p:ajax>

                    <p:column headerText="Row Id">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{myReport.rowId}"></p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Please try to explain the problem and solution in clear words as well, instead of making it a "Spot the difference" game which is almost itching the "this answer is not useful" downvote trigger.

Comment: thank @BalusC, because of the limitations of my english, so sometime i just can show my suggestion, if other people want to know more, i can talk step by step :)